# CSS3 анимация или JS анимация?

Tags: javascript, css3

Как обстоит дело с кроссбраузерностью CSS3 и стоит ли делать анимации на нем при взгляде эдак на год вперед? Или все таки еще разумнее делать на JavaScript. Я понимаю что скоро все будет на =>CSS3, но на данный момент как обстоят дела?
Или будущее уже наступило и CSS3 адекватен в основных браузерах и их версиях?

Comment: Ситуация такова, что если нужно быстро и не на долго (вскоре вновь поменяется дизайн) CSS3. Если же вы строите сам сайт как много все возможных анимаций и т.д. то js (написание гибкого движка).

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо всё обстоит. Даже у keyframe'ов недавно избавились от префиксов. Ну и в Опере 12.1 беспрефиксынй вариант.

Если нужны IE9+, то css-анимации в самый раз. Если нужны keyframes, то IE10+.

А вообще, см. таблицы совместимости и пробуй:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/css-transitions  - здесь кейфрейм в ie10 не сработал :(

Comment: @Димка, там ещё и calc, и порядок префиксов неверный. Тащи эту штуку на jsfiddle и будем смотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Сегодня возможности CSS достаточны для того, чтобы сделать любую анимацию интерфейса в большинстве браузеров. В этом вам помогут библиотеки вроде [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Кроме того уже сегодня можно достаточно спокойно задавать последовательность анимации используя keyframes и/или событие [TransitionEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/transitionend).

В более сложных ситуациях (игры, реально сложные интерфейсы и т.п.), обычно используются анимации на Canvas или SVG. Что тоже вполне себе кроссбраузерно, для этого достаточно взглянуть на парочку библиотек: [TweenMax](http://greensock.com/tweenmax), [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)

P.S. Не забывайте использовать автопрефиксер при сборке проекта, многие анимации до сих пор требуют -webkit/-moz

Comment: "многие анимации до сих пор требуют -webkit/-moz" - только -webkit в animation/keyframes и только в хромах непоследней свежести и сафари.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет поддержки браузерами http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3%20Transition CSS анимация в любом случае будет всегда более производительней чем JS. Если вам необходимо поддерживать ie9 и ниже, Вы всегда можете использовать [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) для определения возможностей браузера и уже потом решать, что и чем анимировать в данном случае.